# setInterval within a for-loop not working

Tags: javascript

What I want is an infinite loop that alerts 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ... with an interval of 2000 milliseconds. But it's not working. The console's not showing any error though. What's the problem here?

```
for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    setInterval(function() {
        alert(i);
    }, 2000);

    if (i == 3) {
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: "but it's not working" --- what does it mean? PS: use `while(true)`, and `i` counter instead

Comment: it's not showing any output on chrome

Comment: what about the condition `i<=3`

Comment: I've reformatted your code, which was really hard to read in its previous incarnation. Please take more care in the future.

Comment: You're essentially creating an infinite loop, with an infinite amount of alerts.  When I tried putting this in jsfiddle, my chrome window quickly consumed 4GB of RAM and the page crashed.  Such is why your alerts are not working, because you've already created a large amount of asynchronous executions before one alert shows.

Answer (score 1):

```
   you can not setInterval() inside a for loop because it will create multiple timer instance.
```

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

> The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until clearInterval() is called, or the window is closed.

The ID value returned by setInterval() is used as the parameter for the clearInterval() method.

Tip: To execute a function only once, after a specified number of milliseconds, use the setTimeout() method.

```
    var i = 0
    function test() {
        i = i % 3; 
        ++i;
        alert(i);
    };

    setInterval('test()', 2000);
```

Comment: "you can not setInterval() inside a for loop. " --- that's not true

Comment: you can do that but what will happen ? it will create multiple timer instance..what the guyz is trying to do looping using setInterval. so why are you preferring setIntervaL inside loop ? is it meaningful?

Comment: "you can not setInterval() inside a for loop." --- there is no any language limitation about that. This phrase is just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This will do:

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    i += 1;
    if (i == 4) {
        i = 1;
    }
    alert(i);
}, 2000);
```

I've checked it chrome too.

It outputs 1,2,3,1,2,3... as you have requested.

Answer (score 0):

You would not need a loop for this, an interval already goes on infinitley. Try this instead:

```
var i = 1;

setInterval(function() {
    alert(i);

    i++;

    if(i > 3) {
      i = 1;
    }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is not working is because you enter the infinite loop in a blocking state, meaning that the interval is never entered as the browser is busy looping. Imagine the browser can only do one thing at a time, as in a single thread, so the loop is it, and cannot do anything else until it's done, and in your case it never is, therefore the interval is waiting for it's turn, which it never gets.

You could make it none blocking like this:

```
function recursion () {
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        var num = i;
        setInterval(function() {
            console.log(String(this));
        }.bind(num), 2000);
    }
    recursion ();
}
recursion ();
```

Answer (score 0):

my best suggestion is . use event monogramming  righterthen loop ,
first make a function then after completing of setInterval call to next function and so on.. that's how u can solve this p